# $K$ finite extension of $F$ s.t. for every 2 subextensions $M_1, M_2$, $M_1\subset M_2$ or $M_2\subset M_1$. Then there's $a\in K$ such that $K=F(a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let K be a finite extension of a field F such that for every two intermediate field $M_1$, $M_2$ we have $M_1\subset M_2$ or $M_2\subset M_1$. I need to show that there is an element $a\in K$ such that $K=F(a)$.

I have an idea that goes like this: If I show that there are finite intermediate fields, then I could use the Primitive Element Theorem (which demonstration wasn't given during my algebra course, so I would have to include this in my solution so it can be whole).

There's also some doubts here: through the internet we can see that some people enunciate the Primitive Element theorem excluding the hypothesis of the extension (finite) having finite intermediate subfields. Which one is the correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need the primitive element theorem. Pick an element $\alpha \in K \setminus F$. If $F(\alpha) = K$ then great; otherwise, choose a $\beta \in K \setminus F(\alpha)$. Using the hypothesis, what's the relationship between $F(\beta)$ and $F(\alpha)$? Try to continue this process. To make the resulting argument formal, you could use induction on the degree of $K$ over $F$.

You probably saw a version of the [primitive element theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem#Existence_statement) that assumes [separability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension), which is a stronger condition: the extension $\mathbf F_p(t^{1/p})$ of the function field $\mathbf F_p(t)$ is inseparable, for example.

Comment: I'll try to check this later today, thanks for the attention! :D

Answer (score 2):

The hypothesis implies there's at most one intermediate field of any given degree over $F$ (if there were two, which one would contain the other one?). Can you take it from there?